# Removing hair dye with baking soda

Tags: personal-care, hair, color

Recently (3 days ago-ish) I dyed my hair a light cotton candy pink. My original hair color is dirty blonde and I only colored it (didn't remove my original hair color). For personal reasons, I need to remove the dye ASAP so I'm thinking on using baking soda and anti-dandruff shampoo (as shown in [this wiki how article](https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Dye-from-Hair)). My question is the following:

Using baking soda as shown in the cited wiki how article, will I end up with super light/white hair or does one recover the original color to some extent?

I don't mind if my hair is a little lighter than it used to be. I just want it to look not dyed/natural. I'm looking for answers to the previous question or alternative methods that may achieve the stated goal (ideally without messing up my hair much more).

Comment: Cut off a small amount of hair, and try it out.

Comment: I changed *"dandruff shampoo"* to *"anti-dandruff shampoo"*. I hope I made the right decision and it does not conflict with your intention.

Answer (score 1):

I add baking soda in the bathtub when I take baths (about 250g per "serving"). I usually take at least one full bath per week, and I use baking soda for at least a year (actually, I completely forgot when I started).

I can tell you for sure that no part of my body, hair or otherwise, got lighter because of the baking soda.

I cannot make any comments on any recipes you may try, but baking soda is not hydrogen peroxide and it is not bleach either. Both of these substances have the actual ability to make you "blond(er)".

Comment: my hairs get white (age or stress related, and I have the skin of a nerd because of lack of sun exposure) - none of which is NaHCO<sub>3</sub> related.